# Alphabetising. How would you arrange names, organisation and publications correctly in one list?

Tags: lists

I want to list twenty people, organisations and journals on one 'Thank you' page. Should individual names be listed by the first letter of their last name and the organisations and journals by the first letter of their business name? What about a journal starting with a 'The'? Your advice is appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about formatting.

Comment: Dear Deadrat - I'm sorry this question offends you so much that you'd vote to have it removed. I'm new to this forum so perhaps you'd be kind enough to suggest the right area to post it?

Comment: Croppers, I'm not offended, and you'll notice that I didn't downvote your question.  It's actually a good question, it's just not one about English language usage.  You may check this link for a list of topics: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Yours is a formatting and etiquette question, and the answer is likely specific to the organization you're working for.  Do they  have a style guide?  Has anyone else you know done this before?  If you're composing this for someone (like your boss), what does that person say?

Comment: Deadrat - I'm a copywriter so I'm usually breaking the rules of grammar (eek - don't string me up!). In this instance I'm proofreading an ebook for a client and although this falls out of my remit, I'd like to advise her with some confidence on the matter. There is no style guide (I've used Style Manual in checking various issues), and the tone is informal. The list in question is for a 'Thank you' page at the end of the ebook.

Comment: Croppers, You're lucky, then, that yours isn't a grammatical issue.  The solution is easy -- ask your client if she'd like the list to be alphabetical, and if so, whether she'd like the list grouped by people, then organizations, and finally journals.  List people by First.MI.Last, and alphabetize by their last names (which may require looking beyond the first letter); organizations by the first word of their business name, ignoring initial articles, as recommended by *The Chicago Manual of Style*.

Comment: As this deals with people and journals I suggest that the Academia Stack Exchange is the place for it. http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Deadrat. That's what I'll do. And thanks Chasly. I think I've got it covered now and will know where to post such concerns next time! Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the possibility of having different sections for people, organisations and journals.  Regardless of listing the names all together or under seperate sections, there are some rules you can follow.

Here is a 6-page file from Dartmouth college on the subject of alphabetising/filing: [**"18 Filing Rules For Proper Alphabetizing"**](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~library/recmgmt/forms/FilingRules.pdf?mswitch-redir=classic)

Some relevant rules from the document:

- Name of individuals are transposed when filed as follows: last name, first name or initial, then middle name or initial.

  > Special cases include hyphenated names, names with apostrophes, etc.  *See the linked file for more information on that.*
- A business name is filed as written unless it is the name of an individual, in that case it should be transposed.

  > Special case: When a business name is made up of two or more surnames, it is filed as written - with each name considered as a separate unit.  *Again, see the linked file for more information on that.*
- If something begins with **The**, you do not file this under the '**T**' unless it forms an integral part of a geographic name.

Comment: Thanks Glenn - that's incredibly helpful of you. Much appreciated.